# How to redirect to the particular web site page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web

I'm developing one web site. In that web site I'm redirecting control to the another site. After completing work on another web site I want to be back on the my page from the my web site.

Suppose I want to redirect on the my web site page that is "abc.aspx". And I installed my web site on the Default virtual directory of my own pc.

I'm developing one shopping site & for payment I'm redirecting to the ccavenue site. And after completing shopping payment from the ccavenue website I want to redirect to the my shopping web site to the particular page , And I don't want to open the payment process on the another window. Than how to do this?

How to do this?

Comment: Are you describing a pop-up window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

internal redirect:

```
Response.redirect("/abc.aspx")
```

this will do the same but maybe more readable:

```
Response.redirect(Request.Url.Authority+"/abc.aspx")
```

external redirect:

```
Response.redirect("http://www.derp.nu/foo")
```

Also put FALSE (as a parameter) after the link if you use session variables:

```
Response.redirect("/abc.aspx", false)
```

you can also do this:

Comment: I'm not having any fix domain right now then how can i use external redirect as u said? I want the dynamic path which will be generated  if i install my web site on any machine .

Comment: @Priyanka Request.Url.Authority will recive the current domain name dynamic even if it change

Answer (score 0):

You'll need that secondary site to perform the redirect. This is typically how ecommerce sites handle their interaction with payment portals.  Alternatively, you could open the second site in a new window/tab, so that when the user closes that window, they are returned to your site by default.

Ideally, you need to give more context so people can answer to the particulars of your problem.

Comment: I'm developing one shopping site & for payment i'm redirecting to the ccavenue site. And after completing shopping payment from the ccavenue website i want to redirect to the my shopping web site to the perticular page , And i don't want to open the payment process on the another window. than how to do this?

Comment: I've never developed for ccavenue, but with every other payment portal I've worked with, you can send a redirectURL in the initial request to the portal (with the purchase details). When the payment has been processed, the portal redirects to that redirectURL. You'll need to check the ccavenue api documentation to find out exactly how they do this. I would be very surprised if there isn't a mechanism in place already though.

Comment: I used the same method what you are telling , i set the redirectURL. It is working in my application, but when i'm creating setup project & installing it on another machine that time it is throwing the error that is page not found. I don't know why this is happening. Do you know related to this?

Comment: http://localhost:1038/SampleWebSite1/CCAvenueReturns.aspx. SampleWebSite1 is the name of my web site & i'm running it on the same machine where i'm developing my application. It is working on the same machine. But i know if i'm creating setup project then it should have another path instead of localhost:1038 , how to detect that path of particular machine?

Comment: you can't pass localhost to the payment portal as it has a different meaning to it. The payment portal sees localhost and it tries to access its own localhost - not yours. You need to pass it a URL that points back to your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution on this, that is-

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/CCAvenueReturn.aspx")`

which will return me the current url of my web site